# JS - Finding a match in array keys using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

There is an array

```
var words =new Array(
            'apple',
            'apa',
            'found',
            'stackoverflow',
            'will'
   );
```

and a variable

```
var search = 'papa.com';
```

Now I want to set an expression like this

```
var Flag=false;
var regexp;
for(var i in words) 
{
    regexp = new RegExp('(^(.*\.))?' + words[i] + '\.([a-z]{2,3})(\.(\w+))?','i');
    if (regexp.test(search)) {Flag=true;}
}
alert (Flag);
```

The loop is supposed to get `words` array keys one by one, then set the regular expression and test the `search` variable against the built expression, if there where one or more match the `Flag` will come out with true.

But, id doesn't work.

Comment: By "keys", do you mean "values"? Anyway, avoid `new Array`, and avoid `for in` to iterate arrays, and avoid dynamic regular expressions. And make sure to `break`! Anyway, what *exactly* is the regular expression supposed to do?

Comment: Also, `(^(.*\.))?` probably doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: Beware the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Optimisation suggestion: As you're not setting a word-specific flag, rather than a for loop consider using `'(?:' + words.join('|') + ')'` where you have `words[i]` currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your escape sequences when you build a regex from a string. This is because a `\` in string literal notation also begins an escape sequence, and so the `\` is removed.

To include a literal `\` character in a string built from literal syntax, you need `\\`.

```
regexp = new RegExp('(^(.*\\.))?' + words[i] + '\\.([a-z]{2,3})(\\.(\\w+))?','i');
```

Your regex was ending up with `.` instead of `\.`, which would of course have very different meaning.